# Time ago in words convert into system date-time

Tags: ruby, datetime, sinatra

Trying to convert strings like `9 weeks ago`, `1 year, 6 months ago`, `20 hours ago` into a ruby time object like `Tue, 10 Mar 2015 12:06:15 PDT -07:00`.

I've been doing this:

```
eval("10 days ago".gsub(' ', '.'))
```

This works fine, but for strings like `1 year, 6 months ago` blows up.

I just need to do comparisons like:

```
eval("10 days ago".gsub(' ', '.')) < (Time.now - 7.days)
```

I'm using **sinatra** so no fancy rails helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please never use eval in production code..

Converting *from* timeago notation would be quite complex and resource intensive.

However, this way seems the least error prone: It will convert a string like "5 seconds ago" to "5S" and use `mapping` to find what it means in time, after which it will subtract that time from the current time.

The parse string is dynamically built so it can accomodate most every timeago notation.

```
require('date')

mapping = {"D"=> "%d","W"=>"%U","H"=>"%T","Y"=>"%Y","M"=>"%m","S"=>"%S"}

timerel = "1 year, 6 months ago".split(",").map { |n| n.gsub(/\s+/, "").upcase()[0,2].split('')}

Date.strptime(
  timerel.map {|n| n[0]}.join(" "), 
  timerel.map {|n| mapping[n[1]]}.join(" ")
)

date = Date.new(0) + (Date.today - Date.strptime(timerel.map {|n| n[0]}.join(" "), timerel.map {|n| mapping[n[1]]}.join(" ")))

 => #<Date: 2014-10-10 ((2456941j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: "Please never use eval in production code" -> Unwise usage of `eval` is ...well,  unwise, just like unwise usage of any language feature. As long as you know what you're doing, `eval` is fine. This applies to many other language features (not just `eval`). In this *particular* case, the `eval` was probably not very wise since "10 days ago" will probably be user input

Comment: Good point. It's just that I would rather speak in absolutes about something "dangerous" such as `eval` to someone (relatively) inexperienced. It's very easy to start thinking "oh yup, this must be one of those cases. let me just bring out the ol' eval" without the right perspective.

Answer (score 1):

It goes without saying that is very error prone. Use at your own risk:

```
def parse(date:)
  eval(date.gsub(/ ?(,|and) ?/, '+').tr(' ', '.').gsub(/^(.*)(\.ago)$/, '(\1)\2'))
end

parse(date: '1 year, 6 months ago') # => Wed, 10 Sep 2014 21:29:11 BST +01:00
parse(date: '1 year, 6 months, 3 weeks, 6 days, 9 hours and 12 seconds ago')
  # => Thu, 14 Aug 2014 12:33:07 BST +01:00
```

The idea is to convert the original string to:

```
'(1.year+6.months).ago'
```